Has the tolerance for the type of question been changed?
I noticed that a lot of questions have been posted on this site and not closed as they should have if we wanted to follow our "living from FE" criteria.
Have we changed the scope of the site?
It seems that we have more contributions with a wider audience, but this will severely affect the overall quality of the site...
Here are some example:
Basic portfolio optimization

What are some examples?

I just added an example. I flagged a few. Maybe I have a wrong feeling because I am in Europe and the mods (that's you and Tal) don't have the time to react. There was another one on futures for example today.

I closed that futures one, as well as the one about write downs, as soon as I saw them. The optimization one seems basic, but only once the asker realizes that it's just a linear constraint. The best answer for this kind of question is a simple explanation to that effect.

The job of the moderators is to close down the egregious off-topic questions and to guide new users towards asking the right kinds of questions or asking them with the right level of "expert" sophistication.  If a question is borderline, the correct practice for a mod is to leave it open and let the community decide.  Although this kind of thing ebbs and flows, there have certainly been times when the community was able to close questions without any interference from the mods, and this is a good thing which is to be encouraged.

Maybe extra guidelines on what is in scope could help. I do not know what to expect from others. There are many ways to become a quant and what is basic knowledge for one maybe obscure for another.

I'm not sure what's your stance in here: Creating a financial market
IMHO looks totally off-topic. I'm surprised only chrisaycock mentioned some reservations. I've been a bit off the site lately, some policy changes I've missed?

I agree with you it was borderline. It might be moved to [money.se]
